# VisualStudio eqivalent to Arm #pragma anon_unions

Tags: c, struct, arm, keil

The Arm "#pragma anon_unions" allows:

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t sensorID;
    uint8_t  messageHeader;
    uint8_t  messageID;
    uint16_t payloadLength;
} Header;

typedef struct {
    uint8_t startOfPacket[SERIAL_SOP_SIZE]; 
    Header; // Anonymous.
    uint8_t payload[SIZE];
} Packet;

Packet packet;
packet.messageID = 1; // Referencing member of Header through a Packet.
```

Any ideas on getting this code to compile in VisualStudio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It compiles in Visual C++ but [only in C mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cx9y4f):

> A Microsoft C extension allows you to declare a structure variable
>   within another structure without giving it a name. These nested
>   structures are called anonymous structures. **C++ does not allow**
>   anonymous structures.